# How to make bundled product and apply recurring on the grand total amount in cart using opencart 2.3.0.2?

Tags: php, opencart2.3

I have a website on "Opencart 2.3.0.2", where I need to implement the bundled product or grouped product concept and apply a recurring on the total amount incurred by two types of products.

So far, I have examined that in this version I am able to apply recurring on each product separately. But I want to apply the recurring on the total amount incurred by a collection of products bought by an user.

I have gone through some extensions but those are only accessible through admin end only.

It means that admin can add some products into a group, but I need, an user can add a number of products and particular product which he/she wants to add in the group and apply a recurring plan.

I will be highly obliged if you please help me somebody to solve out this problem.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand exactly what you're asking. Could you edit your question if you feel you're able to word it any better?

Comment: I need the code by which I will be able to add a recurring payment on the grand total incurred by the products added in the cart by the user using "opencart 2.3.0.2".